# List of items behind header when scrolling in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, header, drawerlayout, navigationview

Can someone help me fix this ? I do not understand why my list of items are going behind the header of my DrawerLayout when I scroll down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#6b6b6b"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/format_appdrawerheader"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_view_item_background"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_view_item_textcolor"
            app:menu="@menu/category_menu">

            <include layout="@layout/format_appdrawerheader" />

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thank's for your help

EDIT : It will be easier to understand with picture.

So, when my app is launched, my NavigationView looks like that. The darker part is the header, and the lighter part is a list made with a menu.
When is scroll down, only the lighter part is moving (which is exactly what I want), but it's sliding under the header. So if I click on a blank space in my header like in the second picture (the frame in red), it selected the item behind, in this example, the "Item 1".

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the problem? When scroll then item goes behind the header is normal behaviour. What do you want else?

Comment: The issue is not about the fact that items are going behind the header, the issue is about the fact that they are still clickable even if they are not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2**

The pictures are helpfull.

You could try to add the next line to the top part of your format_appdrawerheader.xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

It should trap the click event in the header, preventing it from continuing to the view behind the header.

Below I'll show where to put that line if you would use the default Navigation Drawer Activity from Android Studio. You may have to tailor it to your app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:clickable="true">
...
```

Note the last line

I hope this helps. Please let me know.

**Edit**

Another solution could be to remove this line:

```
<include layout="@layout/format_appdrawerheader" />
```

It is already referenced a few lines higher:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/format_appdrawerheader"
```

**Original answer**

I haven't tested it yet, but judging by your description you may need to add the NoActionBar themes to your styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml.

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Please let me whether this helpful or if you run into errors. I don't know how you've set up your MainActivity.java. If you run into a NullPointerException with regard to an ActionBar, you have to make additional modifications to your project. You could take a look at the code in the default NavigationDrawer Activity if you start a new project in Android Studio. In addition to the styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml you could look at the way the toolbar is referenced in the MainActivity.java and how app_bar_main.xml is set up.

Comment: The first part doesn't work. If I delete the line "include layout", all my layout are moving when I scroll (and I only want the bottom part to move). And if I delete the "app headerLayout" line, all the bottom part thats contains the category begin in the top of the Drawer, behind the header.
By using both of these lines, the header doesn't move and the category part begins after the header. This is well working. Except, when I scroll down, the bottom part slips behind the header. And if I click on a blank space in my header, it catches the category behind the header that is not visible.

Comment: And I just discover this, but the scroll bar begins in my header which is useless. It should begins in the bottom parts to be representative of reality. I will add some screenshots, it will be easy to understand.

Comment: For the second part, I can't declare "NoActionBar", I have one in my Activity and it's a strategic part of my app. I don't think the action bar has anything to do with my problem (or maybe I do not understand everything on how the actionbar is working, which is possible given my skills in this area...)

Comment: The pictures are helpful. Please try my new solution.